# how to stretch background image to the full width and also prevent text from overflowing

Tags: html, css

I used a background image for a div and used `background-size:100%` in order to make it full width.But if I use this, then the content inside doesn't seem to stay within the div when the browser is resized. However if I remove 'background-size:100%' then it does stay within. So, how to stretch image to the full with of the browser as well as content to stay within the div?

my html

```
<div class="small-12 medium-12 large-12 columns  middle_1" style="background-image: url('images/kitchen_adventurer_lemon.jpg');background-repeat:no-repeat;background-size:100%;">
               bcjfdbcjdb<br/>
               bcjfdbcjdb<br/>
               bcjfdbcjdb<br/>
               bcjfdbcjdb<br/>
               bcjfdbcjdb<br/>
               bcjfdbcjdb<br/>
               bcjfdbcjdb<br/>
               bcjfdbcjdb<br/>
               bcjfdbcjdb<br/>
               bcjfdbcjdb<br/>
               bcjfdbcjdb<br/>
               bcjfdbcjdb<br/>
               bcjfdbcjdb<br/>
       </div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried setting your background to 'cover'?

```
div {
    background: url(example.jpg);
    background-size: cover;
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

It's not overflowing. Your background doesn't repeat, so it runs out of background.

If your intent is to have the text match the size of the image, you can accomplish that like so:

HTML:

```
<div class="main">
    <img src="images/kitchen_adventurer_lemon.jpg" style="width:100%;"/>
    <div class="text">
               bcjfdbcjdb<br/>
               bcjfdbcjdb<br/>
               bcjfdbcjdb<br/>
               bcjfdbcjdb<br/>
               bcjfdbcjdb<br/>
               bcjfdbcjdb<br/>
               bcjfdbcjdb<br/>
               bcjfdbcjdb<br/>
               bcjfdbcjdb<br/>
               bcjfdbcjdb<br/>
               bcjfdbcjdb<br/>
               bcjfdbcjdb<br/>
               bcjfdbcjdb<br/>
    </div>
</div>
```

CSS:

```
.main{
  position: relative;
  overflow: hidden;
}

.text{
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  overflow: auto;
}
```